# Generate combinations of 2 columns from 8 possible columns into rows

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

i have a list customer ids who are all based in NY state, and 6 possible states they have visited: VA, FL, TX, CA, WA, MN. If they have visited none, we mark as No Travel.

The data is present in S3, and i use Athena to query it.

Sample data looks like this:

| ID | Home - NY | VA | FL | TX | CA | WA | MN | No Travel |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N | Y |
| 234 | Y | Y | Y | N | N | N | N | N |
| 345 | Y | Y | Y | Y | N | N | N | N |
| 456 | Y | N | Y | Y | Y | Y | Y | N |

I want to generate the travel flow of each customer in thpis specific order NY -> VA -> FL -> TX -> CA-> WA-> MN and hopefully capture it on a sankey diagram. How do i convert the data as below with SQL:

| Source | Destination | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NY | No Travel | 123 |
| NY | VA | 234 |
| VA | FL | 234 |
| NY | VA | 345 |
| VA | FL | 345 |
| FL | TX | 345 |
| NY | FL | 456 |
| FL | TX | 456 |
| TX | CA | 456 |
| CA | WA | 456 |
| WA | MN | 456 |

Note: The order is important. For eg, if a customer travels from NY to MN, we will capture as source - NY and Destination - MN. A customer cannot travel in the reverse order: MN -> WA -> CA -> TX -> FL -> NY. And lets assume there is no travel leg between MN -> NY. And the customer can travel from NY to any of the states directly.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Which database system do you want to use?

Comment: Im still ideating and havent tried anything so far. Im using Redshift and Athena.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: added more details. hope it clarifies?